# How to prove the parallelogram law by using geometric method?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

How to prove th parallelogram law by using geometric method?
NOT ALGEBRA

Comment: Perhaps you could state the parallelogram law for those that do not know it (and also so that we know to which generality of spaces you would like to see a proof of the law).

Comment: Define "geometric method", and not "algebra method".

Answer (score 1):

It can not be fully geometric but you can prove parallelogram law by using law of cosines.
If we have paralleogram $ABCD$ then we know that the cosine of angle between $AB$ and $AD$ is equal to minus cosine of angle between $AB$ and $BC$. So by law of cosines
$$ BD^2=AD^2+AB^2-2.AD.AB.\cos(DAB)$$ 
and
$$ AC^2=BC^2+AB^2-2.BC.AB.\cos(ABC)$$
Also we know $AD=BC$. Then if we sum up the last two equalities we get law of parallelogram
$$BD^2+AC^2=2AB^2+2BC^2.$$

Comment: Why does the sum of the terms with cosine equal 0?

Comment: note that $\cos(DAB)=-\cos(ABC)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If the sides of the parallelogram are $a$ and $b$, just evaluate 
$$\|a+b\|^2+\|a-b\|^2.$$ 
Very geometrically.

Michael